# ObjectContent not working but StringContent does

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to write an overload for `HttpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<T>` which allows headers to be set on each request. Looking at the source code for that method, it creates an `ObjectContent<T>` internally, which I tried to emulate below.

However, my target server always receives a null body when binding (using `[FromBody] Form form`).

If I change the request to be a `StringContent` and manually serialize the body, the request succeeds! What could be the difference between the two implementations?

Even more strangely, if I call `await content.ReadAsStringAsync()` *before* `SendAsync` then it also works!

My thoughts are it could be either:

- The JSON is being serialized differently (But I'm not configuring any Json.NET globals anywhere.) The obvious problem would be different capitalization, but as far as I know, JSON.net is case insensitive when parsing, and my server will be using JSON.net
- I'm not awaiting something and the content is being sent before it serialises fully. I can't spot any un-awaited Tasks in my code though, and the entrypoint is a standard `async Main()`

My environments is:

- Client is a simple `netcoreapp2.1` exe, running in a `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine` docker image.
- Server is a .NET framework MVC5 WebApi, with many similar APIs which other clients can call fine

The code below is a trimmed down version of what my client is calling.

```
public static class UserUpdater
{
    public static async Task UpdateAsync(List<string> users)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var form = new { Users = users };
            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["Authorization"] = "Bearer " // Real JWT here
            };

            var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/api/app/v1/gateway-users"), form, headers);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Response status code does not indicate success: " +
                                                    response.StatusCode + "\n\n" +
                                                    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
        }
    }

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, T value,
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var content = new ObjectContent<T>(value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), (MediaTypeHeaderValue)null);
        ////var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); // This works fine
        var message = MakeRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, requestUri, headers, content);
        return await client.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken);
    }

    private static HttpRequestMessage MakeRequestMessage(
        [NotNull] HttpMethod method,
        [NotNull] Uri requestUri,
        [CanBeNull] IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers,
        [CanBeNull] HttpContent content = null)
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                message.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
        }

        if (content != null)
        {
            message.Content = content;
        }

        return message;
    }
```

If it helps, this is the server side (MVC5 WebApi):

```
    [Route("")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public IHttpActionResult Put([Required] [FromBody] GatewayUserCollectionForm form)
    {
        Ensure.NotNull(form, nameof(form)); // This throws since form is null

        this.manager.UpdateGatewayUsers(form.Users.ToList());
        return this.Ok();
    }

    public class GatewayUserCollectionForm
    {
        [Required]
        public List<string> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your api is returning 'application/json'?

Comment: @wannadream It would normally, but it throws a NullReferenceException since it reads the bound form (which is null). It therefore returns a HTTP 500 with no body

Comment: Can you change this line to this?             var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/api/app/v1/gateway-users"), users, headers); I do not see it is necessary to wrap it with an anonymous object.

Comment: @wannadream unfortunately not, the server is expecting an object which contains a list. I'll update with the server code/models but I dont think its the right direction :/

Comment: I see. The structure is right. Just double confirm.

Comment: Can you add HTTP header 'Content-Type', value is 'application/json' and try again?

Comment: No luck. If I pass it in through my dictionary it throws `Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`

I also tried setting it explicitly on the ObjectContent.Headers but that still sends a null body

Comment: Hmm, you'd better install https://www.telerik.com/fiddler to monitor the HTTP traffic. If objects are really posted correctly through HTTP client, the last cause might be camel case issue. Check setting of your API side to see if it does handle that properly.